# Java - removing object from Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a method to remove an element from an array of objects, without turning it into an ArrayList.

This is the constructor for my object:

```
public Person(String name1, String telno1)
{
    name = name1;
    telno = telno1;
}
```

And my Array:

```
int capacity = 100;
private Person[] thePhonebook = new Person[capacity];
```

And i have a shell for my remove method:

```
public String removeEntry(String name)
{
    //name is name of the person to be removed (dont worry about duplicate names)
    //returns the telephone number of removed entry
}
```

Im not sure how to delete the element in the array (i dont want to just set the values to null)

I did think of creating a new array and copying parts on either side of the element to be removed to form a new array but im not sure how to implement that.

I also have a find method which can be used to find the name of the person in the array if that helps:

```
private int find(String name)
{
    String name1 = name;

    int i = 0;
    int elementNo = 0;
    int found = 0;

    while(i < size)
    {
        if(thePhonebook[i].getName().equals(name1))
        {
            elementNo = i;
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found == 1)
    {
        return dirNo;
    }
    else
    {
        dirNo = -1;
        return dirNo;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted -- I couldn't find another question on SO relating to removing an element from an array _without converting the array to a collection_ in Java.

Comment: A very elegant answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26849564/1767041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly remove an element from an array in Java.  You two choices:

**A. If you must preserve the order of the elements in the array:** Begin at the index you want to remove, and shift each element "down" one index (toward index 0), as in:

```
    public String removeEntry(String name)
    {
        String result = null;
        int index = find(name);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            result = thePhonebook[index].telno;
            for (int i = index + 1; i < thePhonebook.length; ++i)
            {
                thePhonebook[i - 1] = thePhonebook[i];
                if (thePhonebook[i] == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            thePhonebook[thePhonebook.length - 1] = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In the above implementation, the value `null` in the array signifies the end of the list.

**B. If the order of the elements in the array doesn't matter:** Swap the element you want to remove with the last element of the list.  Note that to do this you need to maintain a length value for the list, which is the value `thePhonebookLength` in the code below.

```
    public String removeEntry(String name)
    {
        String result = null;
        int index = find(name);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            result = thePhonebook[index].telno;
            thePhonebook[index] = thePhonebook[thePhonebookLength - 1];
            thePhonebook[--thePhonebookLength] = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

A benefit of both of these solutions is that the array is modified *in place*, without using allocation.

Having offered these possibilities, I suggest that using a *collection* is better suited for your purposes -- such as one of the `List` subclasses, or perhaps even a `Map` if lookups by name are common.

Answer (score 0):

To do this is to get the last index in your array and then pass it to the one that was just deleted and the delete the last array.. if the array is the last one dont it just delete it..

```
for(int i = 0; i < thePhonebook .length; i++)
{
    if(thePhonebook[i].getName().equals(string))
    {
            if(i == thePhonebook .length - 1)
              thePhonebook[i] = null;
            else
            {
              thePhonebook[i] = null;
              thePhonebook[i] = thePhonebook[thePhonebook .length - 1];
               thePhonebook[thePhonebook .length - 1] = null;
            }
     }
}
```