# Remove specific index from array in java

Tags: java, arrays, character

Can I remove a specific element from array by mentioning index value?
For example can I remove the character `d` by giving `index` value 1?

```
char[] words = { 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j' };
```

Comment: What do you mean by _remove_?

Comment: delete the character

Comment: Again, what does _delete the character_ mean?

Comment: you can't remove per-say but you can set that index to some value that is not used or you could create a new array with all the values except the one you want to remove.

Comment: if i give index value 1 i need get array like c,f,h,j. if i give index value 0 i need to get array like d,f,h,j. now clear

Comment: [Here's the official tutorial on arrays.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) The first sentence has your answer.

Comment: Use an arraylist and its .remove() method. Arrays are immutable, so you cant 'remove' one, but rather create a new array of length -1 then populate it from the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ArrayList,
*arraycopy* is an alternative:

```
    System.arraycopy(words, 0, result, 0, i);
    System.arraycopy(words, i+1, result, i, result.length-i);
```

where *i* is your index to delete.

Hope I can help.

**EDIT**: Of course you should initially define the correct array lengths:

```
char[] result = new char[words.length-1];
```

Comment: btw, i/you should name it _char[] word_ or _char[] letters_.

also, your definition is wrong, it should be:

`char[] word = {'c','d','f','h','j'};`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not want your array to contain null values, then you would have to make a method that does it. Something like this should suffice:

```
public char[] remove(int index, char[] arr) {
    char[] newArr = new char[arr.length - 1];
    if(index < 0 || index > arr.length) {
        return arr;
    }
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(i == index) {
            i++;
        }
        newArr[j++] = arr[i];
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

Then just replace the old array with the result of remove().

Comment: It throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is the last element. So, instead of i++, one should use continue.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove one or multiple elements from array without converting it to `List` nor creating additional array, you may do it in O(n) not dependent on count of items to remove.

Here, `a` is initial array, `int... r` are distinct ordered indices (positions) of elements to remove:

```
public int removeItems(Object[] a, int... r) {
    int shift = 0;                             
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {       
        if (shift < r.length && i == r[shift])  // i-th item needs to be removed
            shift++;                            // increment `shift`
        else 
            a[i - shift] = a[i];                // move i-th item `shift` positions left
    }
    for (int i = a.length - shift; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] = null;                            // replace remaining items by nulls

    return a.length - shift;                    // return new "length"
}
```

Small testing:

```
Character[] words = {'c','d','f','h','j'};
removeItems(words, 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(words));       // [c, f, h, j, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove an element from the array and "reduce" the array size. Once you have created an array, it's length is fixed.

You could change the value to something that has no meaning or is considered "empty", but you can't remove it.
Another option is to use a list, such as an ArrayList. It has a "remove" method that allows you to actually remove the element from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
  public class Main
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] my_array = {25, 14, 56, 15, 36, 56, 77, 18, 29, 49};

 int removeIndex = 1;
 int j=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < my_array.length -1; i++)
  {

    if(i==1)
    {

    }
    else
     {
        my_array[j] = my_array[i];
        j++;
     }

    }
     System.out.println("Original Array : "+Arrays.toString(my_array));   
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using String class:

```
char[] words = { 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j' };
String str = new String(words);
words = (str.substring(0, Math.min(1, words.length)) + str.substring(Math.min(1 + 1, words.length))).toCharArray();
```

Running in jshell:

```
jshell> char[] words = { 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j' };
words ==> char[5] { 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j' }

jshell> String str = new String(words);
str ==> "cdfhj"

jshell> words = (str.substring(0, Math.min(1, words.length)) + str.substring(Math.min(1 + 1, words.length))).toCharArray();
words ==> char[4] { 'c', 'f', 'h', 'j' }

jshell>
```