# Discard a card after it is drawn

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a "War Game" in which I have an Array (not an ArrayList) and I would like to discard a card after it's drawn to avoid drawing it again. I know some of my friends recommended I use an ArrayList, but my game's already been done and there remains this last trivial problem.

My code is also in French(except for the actual code, there's just french variables, comments etc..) so it can be hard to understand exactly what I mean.

Any suggestions? Code can be provided if needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific index from array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848762/remove-specific-index-from-array-in-java)

Comment: Post your code. How you "discard" a card depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: What about a simple index ? You shuffle the deck at the beginning and then you iterate it, the card before the current index are the one that are already picked (like a real deck ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Go through following steps then if you still want to decide to go with arrays.

1. Convert array to array list.

   ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(YOURARRAY));

   arrayList.remove(EITHER OBJECT OR INDEX)
2. Convert array list to array.

   WHATEVER [] array = list.toArray(new WHATEVER[arrayList.size()]);

Comment: Thank you! I had a few problems, but with abit of thought it clicked in!

Answer (score 1):

Shuffleling the array would create a deck, picking a card would simply be a incrementation of a `int index`. Since you iterate unique values in an array, this would be as simple as that to discard a card, every card before the currentIndex have been picked.

```
int currentIndex;

public Deck(){
    currentIndex = 0;
    initDeck(); //generate cards
    shuffleDeck(); //randomly shuffle the array
}

public Card pick(){
    return deck[currentIndex++];
}
```

Of course, this needs to be secured, Out of bounds exception are still possible here, but this is easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
final String[] suits2 = new String[3]; 
  System.arraycopy(suits, 0, suits2, 0, suits2.length);
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < suits.length; i++){
    if (suits[i].equals("Spades")){
      suits[j] = suits2[i];
      j++;
    }      
  }
```

You can test other cards too but this is very inefficient. Use `ArrayList` instead.